# Strange 1264 Out of Range Error

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1264

When running a set of insert statements in MySQL I keep getting `Error Code: 1264. Out of range value for column 'x' at row 1`. The column type is set to `float(10, 10)` and the values in the column range from `23.912 to 26.458` which are well within the bounds. I have absolutely no idea why I am receiving this error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`float(10,10)` means store 10 decimal places, with no space left for the integer component.

`0.1234567890` would be valid, because that's 10 decimal places, but `1.234567890` isn't, because you didn't leave any space for the `1.`

It's `float(total digits, decimal places)`, and is a sum, not `integer places, decimal places`.

```
123.456789 = 9 digits total, 6 for decimals -> float(9, 6)
```

Comment: That makes a lot more sense. I didn't understand that the left hand limit was the sum of digits right _and_ left of the decimal, whereas the right hand limit was just the decimal places. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For your values `23.912 to 26.458`, `float(10, 10)` can't work. 
Description:-

In float first 10 says you can enter 10 digit in this field and second 10 says 10 digit after `(.)`

So in this fields you can insert:-

```
0.111111111
.
.
.
0.999999999
```

But you can't:-

```
1.111111111
.
.
.
.
.
111111111.1
```